# Power Apps connected form does not show descriptions from corresponding list columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form, powerapp

I created a SharePoint list and then connected it to a form via a Power Apps integration using this tutorial: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps (Microsoft Docs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

Each column in the list has a description that is meant to (A) tell people who are viewing the list what each value means and (B) tell people who are filling out the form what kinds of data should go in each field. The descriptions also contain examples, so it's very important that they appear. However, they've been disappearing at times and I'm not sure why.

Sequence of events:

1. When I originally connected the list and form via Power Apps, the descriptions appeared under the fields on the when filling out a new form (*New Item* on the list view), as expected.
2. I updated the form (added and rearranged fields) in Power Apps and republished it, but then the descriptions disappeared from the fields when I tried submitting a new form on the list view.
3. A coworker told me to change the *Form Settings* selection from *Use a custom form created in PowerApps (requires new list experience) Modify Form in Power Apps*, which was used in the tutorial, to the *Use the default SharePoint form* option.
4. The *Form Settings* switch initially brought the descriptions back, but it changed the order of the form fields so that they no longer corresponded with the column order on the form (I could live with this.)
5. After more changes to the form and another republish, the descriptions have disappeared again, regardless of which *Form Settings* option I select.

My questions:

- What makes the descriptions appear and disappear in this scenario? How do I make it so that the descriptions always show?
- Why are the form fields not in order sometimes when I try to submit a new form, even when I made sure they are in column order in the list and in Power Apps?

Thank you for your help!