# Is there a way to show the SharePoint fields' Descriptions automatically inside the Power App forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint list which have around 50 fields, I provided detailed description about those fields inside the SharePoint fields' Description section, as follow:

[image]

And when using the built-in list forms >> those descriptions show under the fields, as follow:

[image]

But when we created a power app which contain a form, seems the power apps forms will ignore those descriptions, as follow:

[image]

So how I can show the fields descriptions inside Power apps forms? under the fields (in a similar manner how the description shows on the built-in list forms)? any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, there is no native Power Apps way supported for showing SharePoint fields' Descriptions automatically inside the Power Apps forms.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Power Apps connected form does not show descriptions from corresponding list columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/301399/power-apps-connected-form-does-not-show-descriptions-from-corresponding-list-col)
2. [How to get SharePoint field description?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-get-sharepoint-field-description/td-p/51051) - This thread has some workarounds like using separate SharePoint list to store the descriptions of fields
3. [DataCardKey to pull through SP List column description](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/DataCardKey-to-pull-through-SP-List-column-description/td-p/770381)

There is feedback/idea on Microsoft feedback portal for same, you can vote on it: [Fetch SharePoint Field Description and use it in Powerapps](https://ideas.powerapps.com/d365community/idea/4a88c13b-6b74-4971-819f-7881392d8ea9)

Comment: thanks for your reply and info,, but the link to vote is not working

Comment: It works for me. Maybe it is not working for your network somehow.